# ¿Como dar formato al imprimir el contenido de un request en Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, print

```
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'

response = requests.get(url)

print(response)

if response.status_code == 200:

    print(response.content) #Aqui debiera ir el salto de linea por cada elemento retornardo
```

Comment: cambia a `print(response.content.decode())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé a qué te refieres exactamente con "dar formato".

En este ejemplo particular en el que accedes a `http://httpbin.org/get` la respuesta te viene en JSON. Si en lugar de `response.content` usas `response.json()`, obtendrás un diccionario python con los datos ya interpretados. Puedes usar el módulo estándar `pprint` para "imprimir bonito" (*pretty print*) esos datos.

Es decir:

```
import requests
import pprint

url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Y obtendrás en la salida:

```
{'args': {},
 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
             'Host': 'httpbin.org',
             'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'},
 'origin': '35.227.177.10, 35.227.177.10',
 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}
```

Comment: Lo que necesitaba, thanks!